# Generic way to duplicate slices

Tags: generics, go

I have a need to duplicate slices (and part of the underlying array) so a caller won't mutate the original elements of an array.  I think I can write a function to do this for arrays of specific types:

```
func duplicateSliceOfSomeType(sliceOfSomeType []SomeType) []SomeType {
    dulicate := make([]SomeType, len(sliceOfSomeType))
    copy(duplicate, sliceOfSomeType)
    return duplicate
}
```

But is there a way to create the same method generically, perhaps without generics?

```
func duplicateSlice(slice []?) []?{
    duplicate := make([]?, len(slice))
    copy(duplicate, slice)
    return duplicate
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could write one simple statement to make a shallow copy of a slice,

```
b := append([]T(nil), a...)
```

Which is equivalent to,

```
b := make([]T, len(a))
copy(b, a)
```

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type T int

func main() {
    a := []T{4, 2}

    b := append([]T(nil), a...)

    fmt.Println(&a[0], a, &b[0], b)
    b[0] = 9
    fmt.Println(&a[0], a, &b[0], b)
}
```

Output:

```
0x10328000 [4 2] 0x10328020 [4 2]
0x10328000 [4 2] 0x10328020 [9 2]
```

ADDENDUM:

> [Common difficulties with reflection](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/abpF-Ykd0Z0/discussion)
>
> If people are new to Go, they shouldn't be using reflection at all.
>
> -rob
>
> Reflection is subtle even for experts. It exposes details whose
>   understanding depends on knowing pretty fundamental things about how
>   the language works and, to a lesser extent, how it is implemented. It
>   can be bewildering even for experienced Go programmers; for newly
>   minted Gophers there are much more important, simpler things to learn
>   first. Those who learn reflection too early confuse themselves cloud
>   their understanding of those fundamentals. Best to keep it at arm's
>   length until the rest of the picture is clear.
>
> -rob

That said,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func CopySlice(s interface{}) interface{} {
    t, v := reflect.TypeOf(s), reflect.ValueOf(s)
    c := reflect.MakeSlice(t, v.Len(), v.Len())
    reflect.Copy(c, v)
    return c.Interface()
}

type T int

func main() {

    {
        // append
        a := []T{4, 2}
        b := append([]T(nil), a...)
        fmt.Println(&a[0], a, &b[0], b)
        b[0] = 9
        fmt.Println(&a[0], a, &b[0], b)
    }

    {
        // make and copy
        a := []T{4, 2}
        b := make([]T, len(a))
        copy(b, a)
        fmt.Println(&a[0], a, &b[0], b)
        b[0] = 9
        fmt.Println(&a[0], a, &b[0], b)
    }

    {
        // reflection
        a := []T{4, 2}
        b := CopySlice(a).([]T)
        fmt.Println(&a[0], a, &b[0], b)
        b[0] = 9
        fmt.Println(&a[0], a, &b[0], b)
    }

}
```

Output:

```
0xc20800a200 [4 2] 0xc20800a210 [4 2]
0xc20800a200 [4 2] 0xc20800a210 [9 2]
0xc20800a290 [4 2] 0xc20800a2a0 [4 2]
0xc20800a290 [4 2] 0xc20800a2a0 [9 2]
0xc20800a310 [4 2] 0xc20800a320 [4 2]
0xc20800a310 [4 2] 0xc20800a320 [9 2]
```

Comment: So in essence you are appending elements of `a` into a new, empty slice for a new array assigned to `b`, right?

Comment: Is the `append` method as performant as the `make` / `copy` method?

Comment: @Kaiged: The append to a `nil` slice translates into a `make` and `copy`. See my revised answer.

Comment: @Kaiged: They are the same. For `a := make([]T, 256)`, BenchmarkAppend 7026 ns/op. BenchmarkMakeCopy 7054 ns/op
.

Comment: For much shorter use `b := append([]T{}, a...)`

Comment: @Zakaria `[]T{}` is an empty slice with an allocated backed array, not a nil slice. So, `[]T(nil)` is more efficient.

Comment: How about `b := append(a[cap(a):], a...)`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Go 1.18

With the introduction of type parameters in Go 1.18 this is trivial to accomplish. You can write a generic function like this:

```
func duplicateSlice[T any](src []T) []T {
    dup := make([]T, len(src))
    copy(dup, src)
    return dup
}
```

And use it as such:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func duplicateSlice[T any](src []T) []T {
    dup := make([]T, len(src))
    copy(dup, src)
    return dup
}

func main() {
    a := []string{"foo", "bar"}
    a2 := duplicateSlice(a)

    a[0] = "baz"
    fmt.Println(a)  // [baz bar]
    fmt.Println(a2) // [foo bar]

    b := []uint64{8, 12, 30}
    b2 := duplicateSlice(b)

    b[0] = 7
    fmt.Println(b)  // [7 12 30]
    fmt.Println(b2) // [8 12 30]
}
```

You can run this code in this [GoTip playground](https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/BtHyNWgLqBX).

---

#### Experimental `slices` package

The package `golang.org/x/exp/slices` provides generic functions for slices. It will probably be moved into the standard lib <strike>in Go 1.19.</strike> in the future.

We can use [`slices.Clone`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#Clone) to accomplish the same as with the previous `duplicateSlice` function. Note that this is a **shallow copy**:

> Clone returns a copy of the slice. The elements are copied using assignment, so this is a shallow clone.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/exp/slices"
)

func main() {
    a := []string{"foo", "bar"}
    a2 := slices.Clone(a)

    fmt.Println(a2)  // [foo bar]
}
```

GoTip playground: https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/-W3_I0eYLdF

---

#### Reflection, pre-Go 1.18

Here's also an example of how to use `reflect.Copy` to accomplish the same thing before Go 1.18:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    src := []int{1,2,3}
    target := duplicateSlice(src)

    src[0] = 9
    fmt.Println(src)    // [9 2 3]
    fmt.Println(target) // [1 2 3]
}

func duplicateSlice(src interface{}) interface{} {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(src)
    if t.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        panic("not a slice!")
    }
    v := reflect.ValueOf(src)
    
    target := reflect.MakeSlice(t, v.Cap(), v.Len())
    reflect.Copy(target, v)
    return target.Interface()
}
```

Keep in mind that using the `reflect` package will be much slower than using the approach in the currently [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26433284/4108803). Consider the code presented here as just a contrived example for reference.

Link to playground: https://play.golang.org/p/vZ1aQOFTLmU

Answer (score -1):

You can do a copy on any type by using the `reflect` package, specifically `reflect.Copy`: http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Copy

Comment: reflect.Copy seems to have the same semantics as the built-in copy function: it copies from a source into an already-existing destination (and returns the number of elements actually copied) - so it does not seem to offer any advantage over the built-in copy, while being less familiar to many readers.